# android-get latest gps coordinates

Tags: android

I need to have latest gps coordinates when gps was enabled , for example I turned on my gps yesterday , today gps is not enabled but I need to have latest coordinate.

is there any way to get latest user gps coordinates when the gps was enabled ?

Thanks

Comment: please specify question more breif

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the simplest and most robust way to get the user's current location in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-a)

Answer (score 0):

I think that, there is not a direct way to get a "non-existent" gps location. You have to use some of the repository, and then take the data from there. Storing in a database, file, server etc.

Answer (score 0):

[LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String)) might do what you want.